# Setting SUID/SGID permissions to an executable

Tags: bash, privileges, chmod, chown, suid

I want to show, with a concrete example, how powerful is the exploitation of a buffer overflow.

To achive this goal i prepared this simple C program, called "bo":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char* input) {
    char buffer[128];
    strcpy(buffer, input);
    printf("Your input is: %s\n", buffer);
}

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
        function(argv[1]);
}
```

that i compiled with options: -fno-stack-protector and execstack.

Everything works fine and i'm able to lauch my shellcode that opens a new bash.

In my system (Ubuntu MATE 15.10 32bit) i have 2 users: "user" (group: user) and "admin" (group: admin), both having sudo privileges.

What i want to do is to enable "user" to execute "bo" with the privileges of "admin" such that when the buffer overflow happens and the shellcode is executed i have a shell that runs with "admin" privileges (and from this shell, if i run the commands "id" or "whoami" i want to show that now we are "admin").

I've seen that i need to chmod SUID/SGID privileges to "bo". I tried in many ways, but when the shellcode runs i always have a shell lauched from "user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out that i had not only a permission problem but my shellcode did not spawn a root shell.

By the way, thanks to the suggestions of Cwissy, to fully exploit this vulnerability i had to set some privileges on my bo file:

```
sudo -i
chown 0:0 bo
chmod 4755 bo
exit
```

Then with the right shellcode (now i use the one from https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/21013.pdf) i'm able to spawn a root shell.

It is slightly different from my original idea (spawn a shell with "admin" privileges) but this is a good example to show too.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` gives the calling user root user privileges and runs any process as root. the `su` process is used to `switch user`

To ensure the process runs with the admin user privs. the bo binary will need to be `chown admin:admin` and `chmod u+s` as admin.
e.g. if your binary currently looks like this:

```
ls -l bo
drwxrwxr-x user user <size> bo
```

if you become root, then become admin then change the permissions you should get:

```
sudo -i # become root
chown admin: bo # change ownership
su - admin # become admin
chmod u+s bo # set sticky bit
```

then `<ctrl-d>` twice to come back to being `user` and you should see:

```
ls -l bo
drwSrwxr-x admin admin bo
```

of course, you could do away with all the sudo and su nonsense by compiling the code as the `admin` user in the first place, and then chmod'ing it (also still as the `admin` user) before becoming the `user` user.